# Which is the right version when comparing between two doubles?

Tags: c++, double, precision

```
    double d = 0.0;
    if (d == 0.0) {
        cout << "yes" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "nope" << endl;
    }
```

If I have a double of `d`, and when I want to compare it with 0, should not I write like
`if (d < 1e-6)`? (if the eplison of 1e-6 is enough)
But when I build codes like `if (d == 0)` in whatever complier, it always output "yes".
https://godbolt.org/z/Tcvf87P6n
why would that be? So is `if (d == 0)` the right version when comparing between two doubles?

Comment: it depends what you want to do. Do you need to check for equality or for approximate equality? Blindly applying only one when the others is needed will lead to problems.

Comment: you are actually asking two distinct questions. A) why does comparing with 0 work as expected? B) which one should I use? The duplicate is for A. B depends.

Comment: If your double variable has an exact value then `d == 0.0` is fine. If your double variable does not have an exact value (i.e. the value it contains has some rounding error) then `abs(d) < 1e-6` might be better. The difficulty is knowing the difference.

Comment: Note that `d < 1e-6` is not an equality test, but maybe you just made a typo.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition), comparing floating point numbers can be a bit of a can of worms when you really  start looking into it. Things are not the same when comparing small and large numbers for example.

Comment: you need to be aware of the implications. For example `a == b` and `b == c` implies that `a == c`, but `abs(a-b) < eps` and `abs(b-c) < eps` does not imply `abs(a-c) < eps`.

Comment: Exact comparisons between doubles is okay if the values are known (or expected) to be exact.  Floating-point numbers are sometimes maligned because some people expect them to behave like (in the mathematical sense) real numbers.  If the comparison needs "wiggle room", Knuth provided the algorithms to do those comparisons, q.v.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/253874/4641116